# Como hacer un button redondo C# o Vb (Windows Form)

Tags: c#, vb

Quiero hacer un botón redondo para un reproductor, así como estos:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

He logrado hacerlo con el siguiente código:

```
public partial class UserControl1 : Button
{
    public UserControl1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        FlatStyle = FlatStyle.Flat;
        FlatAppearance.BorderSize = 0;
        BackColor = Color.Red;
    }

    protected override void OnPaint(PaintEventArgs e)
    {
        GraphicsPath grPath = new GraphicsPath();
        grPath.AddEllipse(0, 0, ClientSize.Width-3, ClientSize.Height-3);
        this.Region = new Region(grPath);
        base.OnPaint(e);
    }
}
```

Pero la forma redonda se ve mal, como si estuviera pixeleado o como si no tuviera buena calidad, les adjunto una foto:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Quisiera que me ayuden con código en C# o Visual Basic, para Windows Form.

Comment: ¿Que tal si tienes la foto del botón redondo y la pones a ese botón? sería de mejor calidad visual

Comment: No me gustaría poner como Background una imagen, ya que quisiera que el control se pueda usar no sólo para un solo fin sino que sirva para que le pongas cualquier ícono, osea que si deseas poner un ícono de buscar, de zoom, de play, de next, de prev, etc, se pueda usar como si fuera un button normal.

Comment: Esto con wpf sale automaticamente. Por algun motivo no estas usando wpf?

Comment: Uso Windows Form, no uso WPF.

Comment: Winforms es una tecnología bastante antigua, y su capacidad gráfica es bastante limitada. Tengo dudas de que puedas mejorar la calidad solo por código, como te han sugerido probablemente la solución sea crear el boton como lo haces pero transparente, y añadir una imagen.

Answer (score 1):

Recomendaria crees el boton redondo en `WPF`, el cual esta pensado para hacerlo de forma simple mediente templates y ese componene lo hosteas en `window form`

[WPF circle button example](http://www.dotnetmirror.com/articles/wpf/112/wpf-circle-button-example)

[Circular WPF Button Template](http://mark-dot-net.blogspot.com/2009/09/circular-wpf-button-template.html)

```
<Grid Width="100" Height="100" Margin="5">
   <Ellipse Fill="#FF6DB4EF"/>
   <Ellipse>
      <Ellipse.Fill>
         <RadialGradientBrush>
            <GradientStop Offset="0" Color="#00000000"/>
            <GradientStop Offset="0.88" Color="#00000000"/>
            <GradientStop Offset="1" Color="#80000000"/>
         </RadialGradientBrush>
      </Ellipse.Fill>
   </Ellipse>
   <Ellipse Margin="10">
      <Ellipse.Fill>
         <LinearGradientBrush>
            <GradientStop Offset="0" Color="#50FFFFFF"/>
            <GradientStop Offset="0.5" Color="#00FFFFFF"/>
            <GradientStop Offset="1" Color="#50FFFFFF"/>
         </LinearGradientBrush>
      </Ellipse.Fill>
   </Ellipse>
</Grid>
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Cuando tienes el componente solo usas el `ElementHost` para incorporarlo

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[Tutorial: Hospedar un Control compuesto de WPF en Windows Forms](https://docs.microsoft.com/es-es/dotnet/framework/wpf/advanced/walkthrough-hosting-a-wpf-composite-control-in-windows-forms)